# Strange use of `np.where`

Tags: python, numpy

I am reviewing someone else's code which makes heavy use of numpy. In one instance, the code shows something like the following:

```
>>> a = np.array([True, True, False, False, True])
>>> np.where(a)
(array([0, 1, 4], dtype=int64),)
```

I have already used `np.where` but not in this manner. I checked the documentation for the function but found no place where a boolean area could directly be passed into the function, and yet this works.

I am seeking an explanation about exactly what is going on under the hood here? What does that output array represent?

Comment: from the docs `condition : array_like, bool. Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just getting the index where the values of the array are `True`

Comment: Yup. You beat me to it. I will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Within 2 seconds of posting this question, I think I just found it.

I think it is simply providing the indices where the array value is `True`.

Comment: Yeah. From the docs: `When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`